# Не могу выровнять элемент. Как исправить?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, position

Пытаюсь сделать иконку для гамбургер-меню и выровнять ее с помощью флексов. Но не выходит: иконка уходит куда-то вправо, появляется непонятный отступ сверху.

Вот код:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

input {
  display: none;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: lightblue;
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 70px;
  height: 5px;
  background: #000;
  display: block;
}

span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0px;
}
span:nth-child(2) {
  top: 30px;
}

span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 60px;
}

label {
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="checkbox" id="click">
  <label for="click">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Также не совсем понятно почему `label` не видит своих потомков (родитель с `position: relative/fixed/absolute` по идее же должен видеть своих потомков с абсолютным позиционированием).

В чем тут может быть дело?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: lightblue;
}

label {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  display: block;
  right: 20px;
}

[type="checkbox"] {
  opacity: 0;
  position: fixed;
}

span,
span:after,
span:before {
  background: #000;
  display: block;
  height: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  transition: .1s linear;
  width: 70px;
}

span {
  margin: -2.5px 0 0;
  top: 50%;
}

span:after {
  content: '';
  top: 20px;
}

span:before {
  content: '';
  top: -20px;
}

[type="checkbox"]:checked+span {
  background: transparent;
}

[type="checkbox"]:checked+span:after {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: 0;
}

[type="checkbox"]:checked+span:before {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"> 
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox">
        <span></span>
  </label>
</div>
```